# when you use distance filter, how does gps know it moved x meters?

Tags: android

Is there any way the gps is able to do this intelligently, or is it just checking positions with the given frequency, and if the position is less than x meters away, it does not fire the event?

Comment: Is this a programming question or are you simply wondering how GPS works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) documentation:

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of
>   location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider
>   will only send your application an update when the location has
>   changed by at least minDistance meters, **AND at least minTime
>   milliseconds have passed**. However it is more difficult for location
>   providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime
>   should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

So by declaring `minDistance` you are also declaring `minTime`. Provider will send you an update if `minTime` expires and your device has moved at least `minDistance`. So your assumption is correct. Also note that `minTime` is just a hint for provider, you may obtain updates earlier than `minTime` expires again.